# How to display specific column data and row from database to excel?

Tags: vb.net

I want to export specific columns data. How to display only specific columns with data?

**This is what i've tried so far:**

```
For Each dc In datatableMain.Columns
  colIndex = colIndex + 1
  oSheet.Cells(1, colIndex1) = dc.ColumnName
  oSheet.Cells(1, colIndex2) = dc.ColumnName
  oSheet.Cells(1, colIndex3) = dc.ColumnName
  oSheet.Cells(1, colIndex4) = dc.ColumnName
  oSheet.Cells(1, colIndex5) = dc.ColumnName

Next
For Each dr In datatableMain.Rows
   rowIndex = rowIndex + 1
   colIndex = 0
   For Each dc In datatableMain.Columns
       colIndex = colIndex + 1
       oSheet.Cells(rowIndex + 1, colIndex) = dr(dc.ColumnName)
   Next
Next
```

Comment: In your first loop you increment colIndex but you never use it.

Comment: Do you get any error message? If not, what is the result? Is not what you want? I think you should explain WHAT is your problem.